# Driver Start Type Property

Tags: c++, windows, drivers

I need to detect if a driver was initialized in the boot or system ... and I have the variable "DEVICE_OBJECT" to get this information. Researched the properties of "DEVICE_OBJECT" and "DRIVER_OBJECT" to extract this information without success. Does anyone have any tips on how to do?

Comment: You need way more information to get meaningful help, OS, driver, and driver detection library to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
NTSTATUS
IopInitializeDeviceNodeService(PDEVICE_NODE DeviceNode, BOOLEAN BootDriverOnly)
{
   NTSTATUS Status;
   ULONG ServiceStart;
   RTL_QUERY_REGISTRY_TABLE QueryTable[2];

   if (DeviceNode->ServiceName.Buffer == NULL)
   {
      return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
   }

   /*
    * Get service start value
    */

   RtlZeroMemory(QueryTable, sizeof(QueryTable));
   QueryTable[0].Name = L"Start";
   QueryTable[0].Flags = RTL_QUERY_REGISTRY_DIRECT;
   QueryTable[0].EntryContext = &ServiceStart;
   Status = RtlQueryRegistryValues(RTL_REGISTRY_SERVICES,
      DeviceNode->ServiceName.Buffer, QueryTable, NULL, NULL);
   if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
   {
      DPRINT("RtlQueryRegistryValues() failed (Status %x)\n", Status);
      return Status;
   }
```